# How to change the php.ini file on a server

Tags: php

I tried make changes to the `php.ini` file. At first I could not find the `php.ini` file.

I can check `phpinfo()`. There it is shown:

> opt/cpanel/ea-php55/root/etc/php.ini

But in the `etc` directory there isn't any file. I can add a `php.ini` file in that place, but there are no changes.

Comment: Is this localhost or on a hosted server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below given steps:

1. Log in to [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel).
2. File Manager in the cPanelFind the File Manager in the File section of cPanel. Review our tutorial on using the Code Editor within the File manager if you're looking for information on how to use it.
3. Navigate to the directory where you will either save or edit the PHP.INI file and then select the file and use the Code Editor. To open the file, you can click on it to select the file and then click on the Code Editor icon in the menu bar of the File Manager.
4. You can also right-click with your mouse and select Code Editor from the menu that appears.
5. Edit the section of the PHP.INI that you wish to change.
   Click on SAVE CHANGES in the top right hand corner in order to save your modifications or additions to the file.

Comment: you can add the external php.ini file in root

Answer (score 0):

If you are on [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel)/[WHM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel#WHM), I *recommend* you to not mess with the actual *php.ini* file, but set the values of *php.ini* manually in the code.

You can use the PHP function named `ini_set()` to change the values for a specific application or the PHP file. For example, if I want to set the `Display_errors` to `On` in php.ini, I can do that by writing `ini_set('display_errors','1');` and that's all!

However, if you want to change the values for all the applications working on the same server, you can edit the PHP.INI file using File Manager of cPanel for sure! You can navigate to the path given using File Manager. But I don't recommend editing php.ini.

You can add `ini_set` function in your configuration file and it will work on the whole application!